# Cannot see editText

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-edittext

So I'm trying to place an edit text above a `textview` but I'm having trouble accomplishing this. When I open the activity the keyboard opens and when I type I cannot see any text input. Also when the keyboard opens it focuses to halfway down my `imageview` instead of where I'm trying to place the edit text.

here's my xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.zach.BirdsboroClimbing.RouteDetails">
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <CheckBox
            android:text="Route Climbed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:id="@+id/routeCheckBox"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <CheckBox
            android:text="Add Note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/noteCheckBox"
            android:gravity="center"
             />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"
            android:text="Name"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
            android:layout_below="@id/routeCheckBox"
            android:background="#008000"
            />

        <TextView
            android:text="TextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_below="@id/noteEditText"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/routeImage"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: can you upload a screenshot of what's happening?

Comment: I'm away from the computer now but basically it's as if the edit text doesn't exist. I can't see it or click on it to open the keyboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `softInputMode` with `adjustPan` in your manifest. This will make the OS scroll the entire screen by the minimum amount needed to make the cursor visible above the keyboard.

```
    <activity
       android:name=".YourActivity"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    </activity>
```

**Edit** : I answered for the question.You cannot say its not working when you have mistakes on your layout!! remove unnecessary attributes.

You have *layout_alignParentBottom,layout_below,layout_alignParentStart* all of them in that `imageView` (use the exact one you want not all of them)

replace your `imageView` like this

```
      <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/yourImage"
            android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/routeImage"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

Comment: so I placed that in my manifest but I cannot see where my edit text is in my activity. Like if I click the area for where my edit text should be located nothing happens.

Comment: @zsh5032 It woks fine but your layout was not fine that's the reason check my edited answer!!

Comment: OK thank you.  I'm away from my computer now but I will report back once I'm able to try it.

Comment: @zsh5032  did you check the answer?

Comment: @zsh5032  greate next time when you use attributes have a basic understanding about same type ones don't use them all =D and good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Ok! I've found the issue. It arises when you set a drawable to the imageview. 
You have made `EditText` `layout_centerVertical="true"`. 
Since the parent is `RelativeLayout`, when there is a drawable in imageview, the EditText re-calculates its position and goes into the center(vertically) of the parent. Which actually is behind the ImageView. So, your EditText gets behind the ImageView and since ImageView is written after EditText in `xml`, it overlaps the EditText.

Solution would be to remove `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` from EditText.

Comment: Hey I tried your answer as well and it also worked. I wish I could select more then one Correct answer them you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Replace your xml with below

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_route_details"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   >


            <CheckBox
                android:text="Route Climbed"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:id="@+id/routeCheckBox"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <CheckBox
                android:text="Add Note"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:id="@+id/noteCheckBox"
                android:gravity="center"
                />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text"
                android:text="Name"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:id="@+id/noteEditText"
                android:layout_below="@id/routeCheckBox"
                android:background="#008000"
                />

            <TextView
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/routeDetailsView"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:layout_below="@id/noteEditText"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_below="@id/routeDetailsView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/routeImage"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

And Add below line in Activity oncreate method

```
 this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove the padding of EditText if present. It works for me.